# Nodejs r-script only returns NULL

Tags: javascript, r, node.js, rscript

So I'm trying to run an R-script from a nodejs express REST API. I've done everything exactly as described on their Github page https://github.com/joshkatz/r-script.

The only output I get is `null`. Even if the R script only prints something there is no output.

```
.node_modules/
.routes/
...rscript.js
.index.js
.ex-sync.R
```

nodejs:

```
    const out = R("../ex-sync.R")
        .data("hello world", 20)
        .callSync();

    console.error(out);
    // null
```

R:

```
needs(magrittr)
set.seed(512)
do.call(rep, input) %>% 
  strsplit(NULL) %>% 
  sapply(sample) %>% 
  apply(2, paste, collapse = "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You entered the `ex-sync.R` file address incorrectly, chenged to

```
const out = R("ex-sync.R")
```

Comment: Yes that was wrong either. My error occurred because Rscript was not specified as a PATH variable (facepalm).

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually add R-Script folder(C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\bin) to the Windows Path on This PC>Advance Settings>Environment Variables>System Variables